# Storing a decimal number in a text file with just 1 byte

Tags: storage, text-editors

I want to store the number 97 in a text file. In hexadecimal it is 0x61 and it should take 8 bits or 1 byte of storage. But when I enter 97 in a text file, it takes 2 bytes of storage (as it stores each digit as an individual character). So I am wondering is there any way I can store the number in a text file with just 1 byte of storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, the number 97d  in hex is 61h

xxd can store and read exactly the bytes you want.

So

```
C:\carp>echo 61|xxd -r -p >a.a

C:\carp>xxd -p a.a
61

C:\carp>
```

Another way is open a file in notepad and type 'a' and save it as ascii(that's default). Notepad will store 0x61 in the file. Notepad will read it as 'a' but you have the integer value of 97d  aka 61h there in the file.

You can even write an executable program in notepad! You'd need some assembly knowledge and you'd make sure you type the letters whose encodings into binary are the ones you want!

Perhaps you want a program that reads a byte from the file a.a and displays its integer value.  A command would be ideal.. one could write one..

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In Unicode lowercase a is represented as 97. Inherently a *text* file represents characters so storing numbers this way might be counterproductive.

Comment: This is interesting, but doesn't fully answer the question of how to do it.